# Writing a Query with Distinct Count in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm having some difficulty with a query that I'm writing that is meant to display the "makers" that produce laptops with 3 or more DIFFERENT speeds.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Product.maker, Count(Laptop.speed) AS [3+ Different Speeds]
FROM Laptop INNER JOIN Product ON Laptop.model = Product.model
WHERE type = "laptop"
GROUP BY Product.maker
HAVING Count(*) >= 3;
```

This gives me the 2 correct "makers" that produce 3 or more laptop models, however, one "maker", A, produces two laptop models with the SAME speed, so that "maker" needs to be eliminated from the resulting table, which is below.

```
maker   3+ Different Speeds
  A             3
  E             3
```

Here's the Laptop table where the model and speed data is stored:

```
model   speed
2001    2.00   E
2002    1.73   E
2003    1.80   E
2004    2.00   A
2005    2.16   A
2006    2.00   A
```

E produces the top 3, and A produces the bottom 3.  I'm fairly certain that I need to make my Count function DISTINCT, however, I know that Access does not support DISTINCT Count.  Any assistance/suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below query should solve your problem.

```
SELECT
    maker,
    COUNT(speed)
FROM(
    SELECT
        p.maker,
        l.speed
    FROM
        Laptop l
        INNER JOIN Product p
            ON l.model = p.model
    WHERE
        type = "laptop"
    GROUP BY 1,2
    ) foo
GROUP BY 1
HAVING COUNT(1) >= 3
```

First you aggregate all speeds for the same maker, so the inner query would produce:

```
 maker | speed | count 
-------+-------+-------
 E     |  1.73 |     1
 E     |  1.80 |     1
 A     |  2.16 |     1
 E     |  2.00 |     1
 A     |  2.00 |     2
```

Now you have distinct rows for each pair (maker, speed) so that you can simply run a `COUNT()` over speed.

Result

```
 maker | count 
-------+-------
 E     |     3
 A     |     2
```

Now eliminate A with `HAVING` clause.

Comment: After very slightly modifying what you provided me with, I was able to run it successfully.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Accept the answer if it satisfies you. Could you also let me know what did you have to modify?

Answer (score 0):

Your query will work fine if you take out the distinct keyword. If you only group by the maker, then that query will bring you back only one record per maker, the distinct is actually redundant.

Comment: This doesn't cover the problem.

Comment: Although what you said is correct, it does not solve the issue.  The result still displays A and E.  A should be omitted because it produces two models with the same speed.

Answer (score 0):

This is the WORKING query that I came up with, a slightly modified version of what you provided me with.

```
SELECT P.maker AS [Maker], Count(L.speed) AS [3+ Different Speeds]
FROM (SELECT P.maker, L.speed FROM Laptop AS L INNER JOIN Product AS P ON L.model = P.model
WHERE type = "laptop"
GROUP BY P.maker, L.speed)
GROUP BY [Maker]
HAVING Count(L.speed) >= 3;
```

Thanks again!

Comment: This is actually exactly what I've written but with different formatting. I was using `GROUP BY X` aliases to point to a column of `SELECT` statement. Anyways, glad it works.

Comment: I noticed that.  You had the Count() function in there a 3rd time that wasn't necessary, but other than that, it was exactly what I was looking for!